# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I'm noob with pandas, and recently, I got that 'ValueError' when I'm trying to modify the columns that follows some rules, as:

```
csv_input = pd.read_csv(fn, error_bad_lines=False)
if csv_input['ip.src'] == '192.168.1.100':
        csv_input['flow_dir'] = 1  
        csv_input['ip.src'] = 1  
        csv_input['ip.dst'] = 0
    else:
        if csv_input['ip.dst'] == '192.168.1.100':
            csv_input['flow_dir'] = 0  
            csv_input['ip.src'] = 0
            csv_input['ip.dst'] = 1
```

I was searching about this error and I guess that it's because the 'if' statement and the '==' operator, but I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing the `Series` (csv_input['ip.src']) to a single value, hence the error. You can either use boolean indexing to slice the dataframe and set values or `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

So Andrew L's comment is correct, but I'm going to expand on it a bit for your benefit.

When you call, e.g.

```
csv_input['ip.dst'] == '192.168.1.100'
```

What this returns is a Series, with the same index as csv_input, but all the values in that series are boolean, and represent whether the value in `csv_input['ip.dst']` for that row is equal to `'192.168.1.100'`.

So, when you call

```
 if csv_input['ip.dst'] == '192.168.1.100':
```

You're asking whether that *Series* evaluates to True or False. Hopefully that explains what it meant by `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`, it's a Series, it can't be boiled down to a boolean.

Now, what it *looks like* you're trying to do is set the values in the `flow_dir`,`ip.src` & `ip.dst` columns, based on the value in the `ip.src` column.

The correct way to do this is would be with `.loc[]`, something like this:

```
#equivalent to first if statement
csv_input.loc[
    csv_input['ip.src'] = '192.168.1.100',
    ('ip.src','ip.dst','flow_dir')
] = (1,0,1)

#equivalent to second if statement    
csv_input.loc[
    csv_input['ip.dst'] = '192.168.1.100',
    ('ip.src','ip.dst','flow_dir')
] = (0,1,0)
```